# Best way to capture websites in batch?

Tags: screenshot, batch-processing

I have a list of URLs and I would like to capture the related sites as they would display in a standard view port for a given resolution (say 1024x768).

Does anyone know of a tool/web service/script that does just that?

Any standard PHP methods or libraries I could build on alternatively?

To give you an idea what I intend to use these images for: they should feed into a website, my own little place to collect domain names going to waste.

Comment: harder than you might expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web service: [Browshot](https://browshot.com) with the [PHP library](http://browshot.com/api/libraries/php).

Tools: [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I was wasting most of the day searching for a simple solution and finally found one. Ann Smarty wrote this article (http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/take-multiple-screenshots-bulk-firefox/) about the free Firefox plugin Grab Them All, which makes it immensely easy to batch-generate snapshots to a specified size from a text file list of source URLs. Easy peasy, no coding necessary, other than maybe to change saved filenames. (There's a setting that uses a safe version of the supplied URL string, with unsafe characters changed to the underscore character.)

Comment: The plugin is **no longer available** from that link or on the Firefox plugins list.  It says it's open source so maybe you can find the code somewhere and compile it or something.

Comment: for an adhoc one-off of a batch of screenshots from a list of url's, I eventually used https://browshot.com ...  if you verify your email they give you 100 screenshots a month for free, with a bunch of options (and the paid plans seem reasonably priced.)  The only thing is it took a lot of poking around to find the screen where you can upload a txt list of url's... I'd share a link to the page but now I can't find it again.  Seriously.  It had `bulk` or `batch` in the url and was buried somewhere weird on the site.